# Random record from maximum set (with an additional constraint)

Tags: mysql

Two tables, products and producers. I would like to buy a particular type of product, but only from the highest priority producer that makes it, and I need their URL. If multiple producers have the highest priority, then give each producer and equal chance of being selected.

I decide to buy a car for example. From the sample data below, Honda and Ford are the cars with the the highest priority, so return a Honda URL 50% of the time and the Ford URL 50%.

```
Products Table: | producer_id | product_type |  product_url    |
                |-------------|--------------|-----------------|
                |      3      |     car      | wiki.com/a.html |
                |      1      |     bat      | wiki.com/b.html |
                |      2      |     car      | wiki.com/c.html |
                |      4      |     car      | wiki.com/d.html |
                |      2      |     car      | wiki.com/e.html |

Producers Table:| producer_id | producer | priority |
                |-------------|----------|----------|
                |      1      |  wilson  |    30    |
                |      2      |  honda   |    20    |
                |      3      |  mazda   |    5     |
                |      4      |  ford    |    20    |
```

The mess I have at the moment I'm sure can be simplified:

```
SELECT products.url
FROM products, producers
WHERE products.producer_id = producers.producer_id AND products.product_type = 'car'
    AND priority IN 
        (SELECT MAX(priority)
         FROM products, providers
         WHERE products.producer_id = producers.producer_id AND
             products.product_type = 'car'
        )
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

plus it has the problem where it will return Honda's pages 2/3rds of the time because Honda has two models of the three with highest priority.

Looking forward to learning something!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one car, you should randomize the subquery (the Producers one), so that it returns just one random Producer, and then select a random Product from that Producer:

If there are several Producers with highest priority -> one will be selected with equal chance for everyone
If there is only one Producers with highest priority -> that one will be selected

It doesn't work if you need more cars and do for example ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 in the main query... it will select all cars from only one Producer. In this case you would need to repeat the previous method several times, each time with LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

This will work, but it basically calls for your query criteria to be processed 3 times..  Inner most for those that qualify for the highest percent based on the criteria.  The next, re-applies the same criteria, but only gets DISTINCT Producers.  What if in your sample, you  had a producer of OTHER THAN a Car but 20% of their product.  You don't want that producer in the list, hence it needs to be qualified again her.  By doing distinct here, you are getting Honda only once, and Ford once.  This query is ordered by rand() and Limit 1 getting the 50% / 50% you are hoping for, regardless of how many products a given vendor has available.

Finally, the outermost gets only those product URLs that match the provider chosen.  Now, the criteria is applied yet a THIRD time here for car... Lets say you had extra data for "SUV" vs "CAR" vs "TRUCK", all legitimate products from both producers.  You are only interested in the URLs associated with the "CAR" product.

```
SELECT products.product_url 
  FROM 
     products 
        join ( select distinct Products.Producer_ID
                  FROM 
                     products 
                        JOIN producers 
                           on products.producer_id = producers.producer_id 
                        JOIN ( SELECT 
                                MAX(priority) Highest 
                             FROM 
                                products 
                                   JOIN producers 
                                      on products.producer_id = producers.producer_id 
                             WHERE 
                                products.product_type = 'car' 
                             ) HighestPriority 
                           ON producers.Priority = HighestPriority.Highest
                  WHERE 
                     products.product_type = 'car'
                  order by 
                     rand()
                  LIMIT 1 ) PickOne
          ON products.producer_id = PickOne.Producer_ID
   where
      products.product_type = 'car'
```